How to read environment variables with spiders deployed to scrapyd?
TL;DR:
load_env() loads the env vars locally, but it doesn't when runs in scrapyd
Details
I have a scrapy project that needs to read some environment variables. These variables are found in the .env file and I use python-dotenv to load them. It works perfectly when running locally.
However I have a containerized server that runs scrapyd to which the project is deployed (packaged into an egg). I have the .env file included in the MANIFEST.in and I confirmed it is included in the egg.
The spiders run on the scrapyd environment, except for the fact that it doesn't load any of the environment variables that it should.
The project is structured as:
testproject/
    ../setup.py
    ../scrapy.cfg
    ../MANIFEST.in
    ../testproject/
        ../settings.py
        ../.env
        ../spiders/
            ../testspider.py

The settings.py file contains:
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()  # Load Enviroment Variables
print(
    f"Google Cred? {os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')}"
    f" Proxy? {os.environ.get('HTTP_PROXY')}"
)  # It should print the values, but prints None for both

And the .env file:
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=somevalue
HTTP_PROXY=somevalue

How can I load environment variables when running in scrapyd? I don't want to define then in the scrapyd Dockerfile.

I have seen this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964778 that suggests to not use python-dotenv, but it also provides no solution. It seems that the author assumes that the .env file will just get loaded somehow, I've tried, it didn't work.

you can try to specify the path of .env file like this:
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

base_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
env_path = os.path.join(base_dir, ".env")
print(f"Load .env from {env_path}")  # Check the path first.

load_dotenv(env_path, encoding="utf-8") 
print(
    f"Google Cred? {os.environ.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')}"
    f" Proxy? {os.environ.get('HTTP_PROXY')}"
)


I haven't tested this, but the scrapyd-client includes a warning about this Problem: Code using __file__ breaks when run in Scrapyd. See here. I managed to make it work though, using pkg_resources like this: load_dotenv(dotenv_path=resource_filename("testproject", ".env"), verbose=True)
